# Unzip through CommonsMultipartFile

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, zip

I have a app (spring-mvc) and I want to unzip a file but I want to catch the files that it is inside and to be able to work with theirs without save zip file neither files that it has (zip file).

Something like this

```
...
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("file.zip");
Enumeration<?> enu = zipFile.entries();
while (enu.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) enu.nextElement();
    InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);
}
...
```

But I have zip file ("file.zip") through of CommonsMultipartFile (spring-mvc) and no of the disk

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to save zipfile contents to a temporary file, you can read it by using [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html).

```java
 ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(multipartFile.getInputStream());
 ZipEntry ze;
 while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
     // process entry
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I want to get the inputStream of each entry with ZipEntry I don't have it, and what I want to be that

Comment: But ZipFile is not a inputStream and what I want to know is like to do to get a InputStream from ZipFile

Comment: @Celer ZipInputStream is InputStream.